# Submitting webview of own application on playstore

Tags: android, webview, google-play, google-play-services

I have a website and it is responsive to small devices also, so I wanted to publish its webview but google play store is rejecting the application by saying - "We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website, regardless of ownership, or to aggregate content that does not belong to the developer. To resolve this issue, please remove violating content and resubmit your app."

But **I am the owner of website whose webview is used,** additionally in this app push notification, QR code scanner and Geolocation functionalites are also there.

I raise the query in play store-developer but still every time they say the same thing, how to prove them that I am the owner of website whose webview is used in application.

Please someone help me, I am searching for solution on internet form last 7 days.

I also asked them how can I prove that I am the owner but they are repeating the same lines i.e - "Families Policy Requirements: We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website, regardless of ownership"

Please someone tell me how to prove them that I am the owner of website and please let my app get published.

Comment: Did you get the solution? Its too late to comment here but I want to suggest that privacy policy page is also important for app submission. Also verify the site in google search console and analytics with same email I guess. IF you found the solution then share here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this. First verify your website ownership through google search console. There are two methods to verify, using dns or using url prefix. The easiest is using url prefix. Download the html file from google and upload it to your website, then use verify button.